# Fork() - Dois processos acessando a mesma variável

Tags: c, linux

Por que na saída ele faz apenas a multiplicação que é pedida no processo pai e não faz a soma do processo filho?

Entrada:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int pvar = 1;
    printf("%d\n", pvar);
    pid_t childpid;
    childpid = fork();
    if (childpid == -1) 
    {
        perror("Errorr");
        return 1;
    }

    if (childpid == 0)
    { 
        pvar += 3;
        printf("I am child %ld\n", (long)getpid());

    }
    /* parent code */
    else
    { 
        pvar = pvar *4;
        printf("I am parent %ld\n", (long)getpid());
        printf ("Valor de pvar - %d\n", pvar);
        wait(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
1
I am parent 10419
I am child 10420
4
```

Comment: A saída não condiz com o código. Sem falar que seu código não compila, faltam pelo menos duas chaves

Comment: Editei o código, tinha pulado umas linhas no ctrl c e acabei não percebendo que pulei coisa também.